# Toggling Visibility with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

New to JavaScript, and wonder how to use the below code to toggle a `<div>` visibility:

```
var toggle = {

    show : function(obj) {

        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = '';

    },

    hide : function(obj) {

        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'none';

    }

};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing visibility using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205148/changing-visibility-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have HTML like this:

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<span id="blah"></span>
```

In javascript you'll run the following:

```
toggle.show("tooltip"); // shows the div with an id of "tooltip"
toggle.hide("blah");    // hides the span with an id of "blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). In jQuery you could do this in one line:

```
$("#my_obj").toggle();
```

Speeds up development quite a lot and doesn't leave a huge foot print either.

Comment: recommending jquery is not an appropriate answer here.

Answer (score 0):

To display a div you do:
`toggle.show('myElement')`

To hide it:
`toggle.hide('myElement')`

Of course, you'd need an element id named 'myElement' somewhere in your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The link for hiding your DIV:

`<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('example'); return false;">Hide example div</a>`

Example DIV:

`<div id="example"></div>`

You have to set the DIV to hidden in your CSS:

```
#example {
 display:none;}
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script>

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```