# changing visibility using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

hi
i have web page which uses ajax to retrieving data from another pages and while doing that i want to show a loading gif in the page so i've create a div with my gif on it.

```
 <div id="loading"><img src="images/loadinfo.net.gif" width="48" height="48" /></div>
```

here is my css code :

```
#content #loading {
    visibility:hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 48px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

now i figured all i need to do is to set the visibility of loading div to 'visible' at the beginning of my loading content ajax function and then at the end make it hidden again 
but its not working weird thing is  if i create loading div visible and then turn it hidden at the beginning of ajax function it works fine !!!

here is my function :

```
function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';

    var bustcachevar = 1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
    var loadedobjects = ""
    var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname
    var bustcacheparameter = ""

    var page_request = false
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else
    return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }
    if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
    bustcacheparameter = (url.indexOf("?") != -1) ? "&" + new Date().getTime() : "?" + new Date().getTime()
    page_request.open('GET', url + bustcacheparameter, true)
    page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText

}

function loadobjs() {
    if (!document.getElementById) return
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var file = arguments[i]
        var fileref = ""
        if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
            if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { //If object is a js file
                fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
            } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) { //If object is a css file
                fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
            }
        }
        if (fileref != "") {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
            loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code the next time.

Comment: You've made mention in your comments of a "loaded page". Presumably, your ajax is returning some fragment that's loaded into the "current" page, yes? What is being loaded? And how is loadobjs() being used? You've included it, but it's not being called in your code. I used your provided code in a quick test and it worked as expected. Can you point us to a live page?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
function loadpage (page_request, containerid)
{
  var loading = document.getElementById ( "loading" ) ;

  // when connecting to server
  if ( page_request.readyState == 1 )
      loading.style.visibility = "visible" ;

  // when loaded successfully
  if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
  {
      document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText ;
      loading.style.visibility = "hidden" ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display it when you get a response add this to your loadpage()

```
function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
   if (page_request.readyState == 4 && page_request.status==200) {
      var container = document.getElementById(containerid);
      container.innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
      container.style.visibility = 'visible';
      // or 
      container.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

but this depends entirely on how you hid the div in the first place

Comment: no i want to display it while the data is being retrieved from another page

Comment: oh then, changed the container style before you do the request

Comment: display = 'block';
 works but just for one page when i click on the link in the loaded page i get:: Message: Object required Line: 22 Char: 1 Code: 0 and this line is : document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block'; ...

Comment: check if you have an element with 'loading' as an id

Answer (score 1):

Use display instead of visibility.  display: none for invisible and no setting for visible.

Comment: this works but just for one page wehen i click on the link in the loaded page i get::
 Message: Object required
Line: 22
Char: 1
Code: 0


and this line is : 
document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Reads to me like it can't find any element with an id of "loading" you can test that by breaking the line in two: var loading = document.getElementById("loading"); loading.style.display = '';  I don't use 'block' I just use 'none' or ''.  I think default is 'inline' but I just leave it unspecified not sure why everyone loves 'block' so much ;)

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me, max, what you mean by one page and loaded page?

Comment: forget that only one link works(no matter which one) ! after clicking on the first link none of the others work . so i did like you said and break my code now i get the error from the second part "loading.style.display = '';"

Comment: loading.style.display='';       but that isn't your problem.  For some reason document.getElementById("loading")   looks like it is returning null, meaning it didn't find any elements with and ID of "loading" the second time around.   Have you tried to using Firefox /w Firebug?  It may help you keep on eye on things and debug the issue