# Javascript Show DIV

Tags: html, hidden

I have a hidden div that shows when the website is doing anything like sorting out data etc.

This works fine.  The div has a style of visibility hidden, which is changed by JavaScript to visible.

However, I want the div to be shown when the page starts up on one page.

I took out the style for hiding it, but still cant see it.

**CSS**

```
.hiddenmessage {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="HiddenMessageDiv" class="hiddenmessage">
    <img src="~/images/mainlogo.png" />
    <h1>Please Wait</h1>
    Loading Information.....
</div>
```

then I have `<body onload="HideHidden()">` to hide it once the page has loaded.

Comment: Where does the css located ?

Comment: The CSS is in the View file.

Comment: before or after the div ?

Comment: What is written inside `HideHidden()` function? What is your actual issue?

Comment: Try with `display:none;` and `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: read here about [changing visibility using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205148/changing-visibility-using-javascript)

Comment: function HideHidden() {
        document.getElementById("HiddenMessageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be like this

```
.hiddenmessage {
display: none;
opacity: 0.8;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background: white;
border: 1px solid blue;
border-radius: 30px;
position: fixed;
padding: 15px;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Your Script should be like this

```
function HideHidden() { document.getElementById("HiddenMessageDiv").style.display = "block"; }
```

Sample Jsfiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/46eF6/2/

Comment: Hi there.  Thanks for your help, however, since i've been playing ive found out what is happening.  It is not showing 1st off, because the controller is populating the model to pass to it, so i need to show it before the controller starts work.