# How to change div's visibility in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an href that on a click will make one div disappear and another one appear, and I searched but couldn't find how to do it javascript.

For example, I have a div with id "test1".

My guess was :

```
function showTest()
{
  clear();
  document.getElementById("test1").visibility=true;
}

function clear()
{
   document.getElementById("test1").visibility=false;
}
```

So now on one href I can use the `clear()` method and on another the `showTest()` one, but the problem is that nothing changes, so I guess I'm somehow referring to the wrong property? But couldn't find the one I need for this.

Comment: .visibility = hidden;

Comment: @AvinashBabu tried this, but still doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing visibility using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205148/changing-visibility-using-javascript)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If I would have found one, I wouldn't have asked. Please consider your reply before commenting :)

Comment: @TheEmeritus  I searched your question title using google and here's the result: [Click Me](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&client=firefox-a&hs=Zmb&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=How+to+change+div+visibility+in+javascript?&spell=1&sa=X&ei=hwlyVMX3EojnaKu2gJgG&ved=0CBsQvwUoAA&biw=1366&bih=534)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

```
document.getElementById("test1").style.visibility="hidden";
```